# Why do newer versions of awk print large integers instead of decimals?

Tags: awk, arithmetic, gawk, floating-point

I often use the awk (gawk) calculator:

```
calc(){ awk "BEGIN{ print $* }" ;}
```

In Ubuntu 14.04, it output big numbers in standard form, e.g.

```
$ calc 56777654409823*4674990588446667952594759939814064128
2.65435e+50
```

But now (Ubuntu 15.10) the output is never in standard form:

```
$ calc 56777654409823*4674990588446667952594759939814064128
265434999999999985120999032855606532558652107128832
```

What has changed? Is there a way for me to choose whether the output is in standard form or not?

Comment: Reread `man gawk`?

Comment: @waltinator - I don't use gawk for anything other than the calculator and I'm not familiar with its man page. are you implying that a default setting has changed?

Comment: `gawk` from version 4.0.1 and above support arbitrary-precision arithmetic, that change was made in 2012-04-02.

Comment: @cuonglm only when awk is called as `awk -m …` and the version of awk has "GNU MPFR and GNU MP" compiled in. In the OP example that is not the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use printf instead.

```
calc(){ awk "BEGIN{ printf (\"%.5e\\n\", $*) }" ;}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you see in your answer from awk is mostly noise.

We may compare the numbers with `bc` a small utility (around 80kByte) designed to do arbitrary precision math:

```
$ calc(){ awk "BEGIN{print $*}"; }
$ math='56777654409823*4674990588446667952594759939814064128'
$ bc <<<"$math"; calc "$math"
265434999999999978394292482412066060207814915129344
265434999999999985120999032855606532558652107128832
```

265434999999999978394292482412066060207814915129344
   **2654349999999999**<s>85120999032855606532558652107128832</s>

Note that the only numbers that match are the first ~16 decimal digits, which is the precision of Double precision (64 bits) floating point math.

Yes, gawk could perform arbitrary precision math, but only if that has **been compiled** into the program **and** the program is called **with the -M** option.

- Check that the --version contains "GNU MPFR and GNU MP".

  ```
  gawk --version
  -| GNU Awk 4.1.2, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.0-p3, GNU MP 5.0.2)
  -| Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2015 Free Software Foundation.
  ```
- call gawk with the `-M` option.

  Read [15.5 Arbitrary-Precision Integer Arithmetic with gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Arbitrary-Precision-Integers).

You must call gawk as:

```
calc(){ awk -M "BEGIN{print $*}"; }
```

Instead of having to check several details with awk or gawk, please use:

---

## Use bc

bc is an utility used to do math in arbitrary precision:

```
bc <<<'56777654409823*4674990588446667952594759939814064128'
265434999999999978394292482412066060207814915129344
```

Calculate pi to 200 digits (4 times the arc tangent of 1):

```
$ bc <<<"scale=200;4*a(1)"
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307\
81640628620899862803482534211706798214808651328230664709384460955058\
223172535940812848111745028410270193852110555964462294895493038196
```

---

## use the real calc:

After your defined function, you will se this list if you write:

```
$ type -a calc
calc is a function
calc () { awk -M "BEGIN{print $*}"; }
calc is /usr/bin/calc
```

just undefine the function:

```
$ unset -f calc
$ type calc
calc is /usr/bin/calc
```

There you could do:

```
$ calc '2* 3'
6

$ calc '2 ^ 127 - 1'   # mersene prime.
170141183460469231731687303715884105727

$ calc '56777654409823*4674990588446667952594759939814064128'
         265434999999999978394292482412066060207814915129344
```

Which is exactly the same answer from bc:

```
$ math='56777654409823*4674990588446667952594759939814064128'
$ bc <<<"$math"; echo $(calc "$math")
265434999999999978394292482412066060207814915129344
265434999999999978394292482412066060207814915129344
```